# Rails active record efficiency: Model.Create inside a block vs Model.Create(Array)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Would either of the following be more efficient?

```
#Array is an array of hashes


Array.each do |a|
  #some logic to clean up the record for creation
  Model.create!(a)
end
```

vs.

```
Array.each_with_index do |a,i|
  #some logic to clean up the Array for creation
end
Model.create!(Array)
```

Answer (score 1):

Going by the [source code](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-c-create) there is a check which performs a collect on the collection and then recursively calls create.  That being the case, you would be more efficient with the first method as it uses less operations and will only do the `is_a?(Array)` check once.

The source code:

```
# File activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb, line 504
def create(attributes = nil, options = {}, &block)
  if attributes.is_a?(Array)
    attributes.collect { |attr| create(attr, options, &block) }
  else
    object = new(attributes, options)
    yield(object) if block_given?
    object.save
    object
  end
end
```